# How can I install all my python 2 packages for python 3?

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7, python-3.x

I installed Anaconda with Python 2.7 and then later installed the Python 3.6 kernel. I have lots of Python 2 packages and I don't want to have to manually install all of the packages for Python 3. Has anyone written, or does anyone know how to write, a bash script that will go through all my Python 2 packages and just run pip3 install [PACKAGE NAME]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Python 2 pip, run `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. This will write all your installed packages to a text file.

Then, using your Python 3 pip (perhaps `pip3`), run `pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt`. This will install all of the packages as listed in the `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: This worked great! Although I will add that there are a few packages that will throw errors.